# Moving the numbering of equation

Tags: equations, numbering

please, can you put the numbering of my expression to the end of a row after the fraction. I tried 2 different ways, but it is stiil not good enough. These equations are the same, so enough change just one of them. 
Thanks in advance[image]

First equation:

```
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
t^{\text{same rode}}_{j} = \frac{-(speed_j - speed_0) \pm \sqrt{\left(speed_j - speed_0\right)^2 \pm 2\cdot\left(accel_j - accel_0\right)\cdot \left(r-d^{\text{between 0 and j}}\right)}}{accel_j - accel_0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

Second equation:

```
\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation} \label{eq1}
    \begin{split}
      \MoveEqLeft\mathrlap{t^{\text{same rode}}_j =}\\
       & = \frac{-(speed_j - speed_0) \pm \sqrt{\left(speed_j - speed_0\right)^2 \pm 2\cdot\left(accel_j - accel_0\right)\cdot \left(r-d^{\text{between 0 and j}}\right)}}{accel_j - accel_0}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) plase post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. That makes it a lot easier for others to test your code and give advise. (3) Does this even compile?  Having `equation` inside `fleqn` does not make sense. (4) that said your math is clearly too wide for the line width so the eq nums are moved out  of the way. It is probably best here to rewrite the equation. For example by no having such long variable names.

Comment: Note you should use `\mathrm{speed}` or `\mathit{speed}` never set multi-letter words in the default math italic font it is designed to separate the letters like a product of variables, not look like a word.  The equation number moves to the end if the page width is wide enough, and you have not provided a full document so not given any indication of how wide your page is, or if you can change it. adding `\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}` in the preamble for example might work.

Comment: mostly the equation is so wide because of `text{between 0 and j}` (which should be `\text{between $0$ and $j$}` so the fonts for 0 and j match) does it have to be so long in the expression, not something more compact like `d^{0\leq i \leq j}` ??

Comment: No, it is not, your link was resolved and this was another equation, just a little bit simillar

Answer (score 1):

You can split the equation over a couple of lines and use an `aligned` inside the square root.  You really don't need any of the `\left...\right` pairs.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      &t^{\text{same road}}_{j} \\
      &= \frac{
        -(\mathrm{speed}_j - \mathrm{speed}_0)
        \pm \sqrt{
        \begin{aligned}
          &(\mathrm{speed}_j - \mathrm{speed}_0)^{\mathstrut2} \\
          &\pm 2\cdot(\mathrm{accel}_j -
            \mathrm{accel}_0)\cdot (r-d^{\text{between $0$
            and $j$}})
        \end{aligned}
            }
            }{\mathrm{accel}_j - \mathrm{accel}_0}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```